# Associate reply email with an existing record of custom object

Tags: apex, email

Seeking some email service related insight here for a roadblock I have. Any help will be much appreciated.

When Mr. X replies to an email originally sent by Mr. Y from Custom Object's record CR-REC-1 via 'Send Email' button in Salesforce, how can we associate that reply email sent by Mr. X back to the record CR-REC-1 and may be even store that email in the particular record either in a custom text field or as a task?

All the examples/guides I have found so far only demonstrates the creation of new record...

Can we may be use *reference* atttribue in InboundEmail object?

Answer (score 1):

One easyish avenue: if you can shift the email activity across to `Email to Case (On-Demand)`, then Salesforce will automatically reconcile the incoming email back onto a Case (on your Contact).

This takes care of the non-trivial tasks of receiving the email response into Salesforce, fishing out the reference number and tying it up with the correct conversation.

While it would necessitate all your interactions happening from the `Case` object, it is then a very small step to append that email to your record of choice, Custom Object, or task etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input user320! Trying to store the email as .msg attachment instead.